# Why do I keep getting this error when creating an array that is a double?

Tags: java, arrays, double

```
System.out.print("How many QUIZ scores? ");
double howManyQuizzes = input.nextDouble();
double[] quizScoresArray = new double[howManyQuizzes];

System.out.print("Enter QUIZ scores: ");
for (double i = 0; i < howManyQuizzes; i++)
{
    quizScoresArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
}

System.out.println(" ");
```

I'm trying to write a program that calculates your grade for a class. It takes into account how much quizzes, exams, programs, etc are worth.

I am having issues with this part of my code. I'm confused as to why my code won't compile. I am trying to create a type double array because the values that we are putting in for the quiz scores MUST be double values. However, when I compile my program, I keep getting this error that says, ***"incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int."*** I'm not sure why this is happening, and was wondering if anyone could provide some insight. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot create an array using a double for the length.

Comment: You are using `double` which can hold value like `2.33`. What should be result of `new double[2.33]`? Also what value should be returned for index `yourArray[0.25]`?

Comment: `howManyQuizzes` needs to be an `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate the `for` loop using a `double` variable, so change it to `int` data type as shown below:

```
int howManyQuizzes = input.nextInt();
```

Also, the `for` loop should be iterating with `int` values from 0, 1, ...till `howManyQuizzes-1` values

```
for (int i = 0; i < howManyQuizzes; i++) {
    quizScoresArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
```

> I didn't know that you couldn't use a double variable to iterate a for
>   loop!

`double` holds decimal data, so your iteration (if it were ever possible) will be like 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc.. (also infinite numbers in between), which is not possible. 
So your loop counter should be `int` type which will iterate from 0, 1,... till `howManyQuizzes-1` values (because integers do not hold any intermediate values in between 0 and 1 or 1 and 2 etc.., simple maths)

Comment: Oh wow! Such a simple answer lol. Thank you so much! I didn't know that you couldn't use a double variable to iterate a for loop!

Comment: You can also use another letter instead of `i` as the loop variable.

Comment: `double` is a decimal type, so do you want to iterate 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc..? So, we need `int` type

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array, the size must be an integer. Actually you are given double as size.
Change this line

```
double howManyQuizzes = input.nextDouble();
```

to

```
int howManyQuizzes = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Yes short is also acceptable, java will promote it to int

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] quizScoresArray = new double[howManyQuizzes];
```

this is wrong, you cannot declare an array with double value, instead you MUST use int.

```
System.out.print("How many QUIZ scores? ");
int howManyQuizzes = input.nextInt();
double[] quizScoresArray = new double[howManyQuizzes];
```

Comment: And only positive `int`.